# admob interstitial ad iOS with video play

Tags: ios, video, admob, interstitial

I am  building app with table view cell which contain vidoe I add interstitial ad but it show when I click the cell and I have to click the cell again to play the video.. Is there is way to make it play automatically after ad load

my code:

```
{
    import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import AVKit
    import GoogleMobileAds

    class channelsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
    {

        var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

        var table = [Videos]()
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        
        @IBOutlet var Tableview: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() 
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
            interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
            let request = GADRequest()
            interstitial.load(request)
            
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("videos")
            
            ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                if ( snapshot.childrenCount > 0 ) 
                {
                    self.table.removeAll()
                    
                    for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] 
                    {
                        
                        let Object = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let Title = Object?["Title"]
                        let videolink = Object?["link"]
                        
                        
                        let video = Videos(Title: Title as! String, link: videolink as! String)
                        self.table.append(video)
                        
                        self.Tableview.reloadData()
                        
                    }
                }
                
            })
            
            
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return table.count }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
        {
            let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
            
            let video: Videos
            
            video = table[indexPath.row]
            cell.TitleCell.text = video.Title
            
            return cell
     
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
        {
            guard let videoURL = URL(string: table[indexPath.row].link!) else { return }

            if interstitial.isReady { interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self) }

            func createad() -> GADInterstitial 
            {
                let inter = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
                inter.load(GADRequest())
                return inter
                
            }
            
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
            
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = player
            present(controller, animated: true) 
            {
                                
                player.play()
      
                self.interstitial = createad()
                  
            }
        
          
        }
            
        
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
        {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: use rewarded ad instead of interstitial ads https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-ads

Comment: I want to use interstial ad did dismiss

Comment: I need to use interstial did dismiss